# Q: What should I use to create simple local web app that stores and give out information

Tags: web-applications, localserver

I am just a regular employee with a "clerical/paper work job" and I just wanted to automate my work and make it more easily for me to grab the information i would need.

I have learned a little bit of: HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, c# and right now im trying to learn Node.js.

So, my question is: What would be the best way, to create a local web app, for someone with a really little knowledge about coding. (I am open with any languages and databases and im willing to learn, i just dont know where to start).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Django framework to be one of the easiest to work with for beginners.  It takes care of a lot of stuff for you, especially regarding interacting with a database and creating an admin site.

The documentation is also really really good and the intro tutorial walks you through everything you need to know:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

Its written in Python, which is a fairly friendly language to learn for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possible answers, but it basically boils down to what you need your app to do. 
Since you need to 'grab information more easily' I'd say use a SQL tutorial to get started, then gradually modify it to make it your own.

Some examples are:

https://www.taniarascia.com/create-a-simple-database-app-connecting-to-mysql-with-php/

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=kN1Czs0m1SU

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/820391/a-very-simple-example-of-html-offline-database-ind

Just try different things: most important is to just start something.